# Why does "$dx$ becomes 0" when solving derivatives?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose an example where you are told to find the derivative of any function say, $x^2$.

$$\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{f(x + \Delta x ) - f(x)}{\Delta x}$$

Using $f(x) = x^2$, and upon solving you're left with:

$$\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = 2x + \Delta x$$

And to get the actual result, I was told to substitute $\Delta x = 0$ and that is my question. How does it make sense to do so?

[image]

Comment: Well, try _not_ doing so and see what happens. Calculus of [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) has its applications, after all.

Comment: PS: I have no idea how to make the math fonts size larger.

Comment: If you want a formula on a line of its own, enclose it with `$$` instead of `$`. (That also makes some things, e.g. fractions, larger.)

Comment: Use \displaystyle or \dfrac, I guess. $\frac{df}{dx}$ will be $\dfrac{df}{dx}$.

Comment: Do you know what a limit is?

Comment: An abstract infinitesimal is an arbitrarily or indefinitely small value. It can be made immeasurable regardless of how you define that. In other words - just because you can't put a value on it, it doesn't mean it's zero. But you can neglect it anyway. [Relevant](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852394/failure-of-differential-notation/1651264#1651264).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the derivative is **defined** as

$$f'(x) = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}$$

So, for example, if the function $\Delta x \mapsto \frac{f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}$ is continuous **around** $\Delta x = 0$, then you can calculate the limit by simply plugging in $\Delta x=0$.

Comment: Exactly. When using the definition to calculate derivatives, you just need to work on the expression first so it doesn't become "$\frac00$" when you carry out the substitution $\Delta x \to 0$.

Comment: I saw but I want to know why does it become 0 and how does it make sense in case of slope?

Comment: @cpx If $g(x)$ is continuous at $0$, then $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x) = g(0)$.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what "continuous" is. I updated the question with a diagram. Can you say that in layman terms perhaps?

Comment: @cpx If you don't know what continuous is, you have no business calculating derivatives. Sorry, but that's the blunt truth. You have to learn to walk before you can run.

Comment: With the sine at $x=0$, we have $f'(0)=\frac{\sin(\Delta x)}{\Delta x}$ and obviously this is continuous around $\Delta x=0$, but you certainly cannot plug in $\Delta x=0$, can you? You meant something slightly different, I guess.

Comment: @egreg You cannot, because the expression is *not* continuous around $0$, because it is not **defined** at $0$.

Comment: @5xum ***No*** expression of the form $\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$ is defined at $\Delta x=0$.

Comment: @egreg No, but the expression $2x + \Delta x$ **IS**.

Comment: @5xum This is exactly why people get confused when learning derivatives.

Comment: @egreg Yeah. I would improve my answer, but I don't have the motivation. The OP clearly says he does not know what *continuous* means. As far as I am concerned, it makes no sense to explain derivatives to someone who knows nothing about continuity.

Comment: @5xum: Sorry if you feel discouraged but I just picked up that simple little concept while I was looking and your answer would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The finite-difference expression $g(x,\Delta x)=\dfrac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$ is depending on two parameters, $x$ and $\Delta x$. The first indicates a "location", and the second a "scale".

Working with these two parameters is much more complicated than a single one, and calculus would certainly have made much slower progress without the possibility of getting rid of the scale.

It turns out that when the functions are smooth (local fluctuations decreasing with scale), the finite difference stabilizes to a constant value when you reduce $\Delta x$, and this constant value is representative of the local behavior of the function.

Hence, by convention you extend $g(x,\Delta x)$ to $g(x,0)$ by assigning this constant value.

---

Actually, the nuance between finite-difference and derivative (infinitesimal difference if you like) indeed appears in your example

$$\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta x}=2x+\Delta x,$$
which is more complicated than
$$\frac{df}{dx}=2x.$$
The difference may seem futile, but you quickly see that it is not:

$$\frac{\cos(x+\Delta x)-\cos(x)}{\Delta x}=\frac{\cos(x)\cos(\Delta x)-\sin(x)\sin(\Delta x)-\cos(x)}{\Delta x}$$ does not simplify, whereas
$$\cos'(x)=-\sin(x).$$