# How is the second derivitive derived?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

As everyone knows that the derivitive of a function is notated as $\frac{dy}{dx}$

The question is:
How is the second derivitive $\left(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right)$ notation derived?

Comment: That's a notation for the second derivative.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852394/failure-of-differential-notation

Comment: Is the question asking about the definition of a second derivative, the rationale for the notation for a second derivative, or for some historical perspective on such a notation?  As above, the Question is unclear in its present statement.

Comment: Think of the derivative of being *two* operations rather than one---a differential followed by a division by dx.  Now the differential of a variable is d(varname) or just dvarname.  The differential applied twice is d(d(varname)), or, as a convenience, this can be written as d^2 varname.

Therefore, since the derivative is a differential followed by a division by dx, it is d^2y/dx^2 because you are doing the differential of y twice, and dividing by dx twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just notation. Let $y=f(x)$. Then $\frac d{dx}(y)=f'(x)$.  Now
$$f''(x)=\frac d{dx}\left(\frac d{dx}(y)\right)=\left(\frac d{dx}\right)^2(y)=\frac {d^2}{dx^2}(y).$$

Comment: so $\frac{d}{dx}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$. Ok its not a fraction, guess I have to accept this explanation.

Comment: @KennyGuy The notation is confusing: These manipulations are not really rigorous, else you could rearrange it to get things like $d\cdot \frac {dy}{dx^2}$ which makes no sense.

Comment: The idea is that $d/dx$ is an operation on functions which sends a function to it's derivative.  $(d/dx)^2$ would denote applying the operator twice in succession.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD You are absolutely right about rigor here.  This is not so much a derivation as an explanation of the notation.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted OP not to feel deceived by the notation, in any way, we could just say $\frac {d^2}{dx^2}$  looks much better than $\frac d {dx} \frac d{dx}$ :-P (although the operator approach is much believable).

Answer (score -3):

**Edit**: I misread the OP question and thought that practical examples were asked for.

The second derivative arises from considering the first derivative as an independent function, and is obtained by derivation.
Notation (like the other answerer mentioned), is mainly of two types:
Leibniz notation or:
$ {d\over dx} (f(x))$ is the first order derivative
${d\over dx} ({d\over dx}(f(x)) = {d^2\over dx}f(x)$

Lagrange Notation instead uses "prime" marks:
Derivative of $f(x) = f'(x)$, derivative of $f'(x) = f''(x)$ and so on.

Practical example:
$$
f(x) = x^3
$$
$$
f'(x) = {d\over dx}f(x) = 3x^2
$$
$$
f''(x) = {d\over dx}f'(x) = 6x
$$
A pratical example is however the change in kinetic energy of a moving body.

Comment: That's not really the question (if I understood correctly, the OP is asking about the notation, not the meaning or use of the second derivative).

Comment: Fair, but a use of the second derivative in a practical application is in fact the example I gave. Edit: Misread original post, will change answer to reflect it.